# Costliness of converting a String to a StringBuilder

Tags: c#, string, stringbuilder

Is it costly converting a string to a StringBuilder in C#? I was looking for
the time complexity of the call below.

```
StringBuilder sentence = new StringBuilder("some string");
```

Comment: Write a test. You can do it. I think it's pretty safe to estimate O(1) given that each declare/instantiate is discrete and doesn't affect the previous/next one.

Comment: https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/text/stringbuilder.cs,101

Comment: @Stijn This question asks about the complexity of the *constructor*, not `ToString()`

Comment: @Amy The body did, but the title didn't. I corrected that.

Comment: @Rozar,  I would recommend doing a google search and understanding the difference between mutable vs immutable strings for starters

Comment: I don't get your concern. It should be O(1). It it one statement.  Are you asking if it is O(n) based on number of characters in the string?

Comment: @paparazzo How in the world is the number of statements involved related to the asymptotic complexity?  A single statement could have *any* asymptotic complexity whatsoever, especially when, like is seen here, that one statement is merely calling some other complex operation defined elsewhere that's doing who-knows-what.

Comment: @Servy It was a simple question.  How in the world do you take exception?

Comment: @paparazzo I don't take exception to the question; the question is fine.  I take exception to your statement that it's O(1) because it's one statement.

Comment: @Servy Read that again.  Calling any statement is O(1).  What is behind the statement may or may not be O(1).

Comment: @paparazzo Calling a statement can have any big oh value, because calling one statement could do *literally anything*, depending on what that statement is defined to do.  Some will be O(1), some will be all sorts of other things.  The number of statements called has nothing to do with the big oh value.

Comment: @Servy Not going to argue semantics with you.

Answer (score 1):

According to the reference source (https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/text/stringbuilder.cs,101), the `StringBuilder` constructor copies the source string's characters, therefore the time complexity will be O(n) where n is the string length.